# SQL Count based on time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have thousands of customers orders.
I just need a count of all orders placed after 5:00 PM going back to the very first entry.
How would I query this?

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Nop_Order
WHERE (CreatedOn > '???')
```

Comment: Do you want the orders on a particular date, e.g. today?  Or any order placed after 1700 hours and prior to midnight on every day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to isolate just the time component of the date, and compare it to `17`, which would be 5:00 PM in military time...

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Nop_Order
WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR, CreatedOn) >= 17)
```

Comment: this will include orders placed at 5pm exactly

Comment: Beat me too it.. I posted mine before I saw yours

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS TotalOrders
from Nop_Order where datepart(hh, CreatedOn) > 17
```